# Nvidia driver files automatically being deleted prior to setup.exe running

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm running Windows 10 and have a GeForce GTX 1080. My current driver version is 436.30. I downloaded version 457.30 and am trying to install it. When I launch the exe, the files unzip to the default directory that the installer chooses. However, before setup.exe runs, all the files which were unzipped disappear. All that is left is c:\NVIDIA. It is empty. The install failed when I tried it from GeForce Experience, too. I suspect the same thing was happening, but can't say for sure.

Why are these files just vanishing? Also, it's absurd that the driver install is 600MB. The driver should be just a couple megs, if that. A barebones driver install would sure be nice.

Comment: I have installed that driver on my side without any issue, did you try to run it as administrator? Also we could try to run it in clean boot environment （https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows）which could help us to eliminate third party software affection.

Comment: I had tried to run it as Admin and that didn't work. The clean boot idea was great (!), but unfortunately it didn't make a difference. :( I could see files unzipping into the target directory and then when almost at the end, poof! All gone.

Comment: how about go to device manager, find graphic driver and update it through browser my computer to install driver?

Comment: I used your suggestion along with a complete hack. I created a temp directory, and when the NVIDIA setup was about 80% done unzipping the files, I copied and pasted what was there into my temp folder. It got most of the way done copying before the install nuked the files. Mine stayed. I got enough files, apparently, to update the driver via Device Manager. It seems to have succeeded and to have stuck. Thanks for the ideas, Joy! Looks like I'm good to go. I miss the old days of a 10K inf file. Right click and install. Done. (CUDA is now an option for me in Davinci Resolve!)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the conversation but the fix is to extract the exe with winrar or another service into a folder then you can run the installer. All the exe is, is a self extracting program so it can be treated as a zip file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me.

1. Download drivers directly from NVidia
2. Right-click the .exe file and open it with an extraction tool (winzip, 7zip, etc)
3. Extract the files to some folder.
4. Use device manager to update the drivers from files on the drive. Point to the folder you just extracted everything into.

Doing that should install the updated drivers without having to hope you copied everything before the driver files delete delete themselves.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. There was a Windows update waiting for a restart. After that the installer extracted the files and I could continue with the installation.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue as Birdus, all the files would automatically delete themselves immediately after extraction. No amount of Admin rights, updates, or restarts did anything. The only solution was Birdus's solution, e.g. quickly copy off the files during the extraction before they auto-deleted and manually select them from the Device Manager.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1210144)